# Can anyone help clarifying the geometry in this probability, random variables question.

Tags: probability, random-variables

So basically the question is to find the CDF of $Z$ where $Z$ is the random variable that signifies the distance from a point in a square(sides 1 length) to a fixed vertex of the square. I do not understand the calculation of the geometry in the following picture :[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $AB = 1$ and $AE = t$, so by the pythagorean theorem, $BE = \sqrt{t^2 - 1}$. That means that the triangle $\triangle ABE$ has area $\sqrt{t^2 - 1}/2$. The triangle $\triangle ADF$ is congruent, so it has the same area, and therefore, the total area of those two triangles is $\sqrt{t^2 - 1}$. That takes care of the first term.

The second term, then, is the area of the sector $AEF$. The area of a sector of radius $t$ and angle $\theta$ (in radians) is equal to $\frac{\theta t^2}2$. We see the factor $\frac{t^2}{2}$ there, so what's left is to show that what's in the brackets is really $\theta = \angle EAF$.

But $\theta$ is the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ of the corner of the square, minus the two angles $\angle DAF$ and $\angle BAE$. These two angles are equal, and we know that they're the angle of a triangle with adjacent leg $1$ and opposite leg $\sqrt{t^2 - 1}$. That means that the angle is $\arctan\sqrt{t^2 - 1}$. Therefore
$$
\angle EAF = \angle BAD - 2\angle BAE\\
= \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\arctan\sqrt{t^2 - 1}
$$
and we're done.

Note that this is only valid for $t > 1$. For smaller $t$, the calculation is much simpler, of course.

Comment: Could you help with the expected value here? In my book it says that for $t \in (0,1)$ the CDF is $\frac{t^2 \pi}{4}$ and it finds the expected value like: $E(X)= \int_{0}^{ \sqrt{2}}t dF_z(t)$ but doesn't this have to be divided into two integrals because of the different CDF's ?

Comment: Could you maybe post a question for me that I really need? Ive already asked 6 today so I need some help?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Well, technically, it's just one integral, with 
$$
F_z(t) = \cases{\frac{t^2\pi}{4} & if $0 \leq t < 1$\\\sqrt{t^2 - 1} +\frac{t^2}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\arctan\sqrt{t^2 - 1}\right) & if $1< t \leq \sqrt{2}$\\0& otherwise}
$$
but to _calculate_ that integral, it would be a good idea to split into two integrals.

Comment: The density of  the  random variable X is : $f(x)= {x^{m-1}\over m!}e^{-x}, x>0$ Find $EX^2$

Comment: Would I be able to do this like: $\int_{- \infty }^{\infty }x^2 f(x)dx ?$

Comment: @BozoVulicevic You really should post separate questions as separate questions.

Comment: I would but I can;t as I've already asked my limit of 6 today, so I ask here, if you could help ?